# Ruby 2.0.0 stuck on compiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I wonder if any one has the same issue. I tried to install ruby 2.0.0-p353 on my mac. But currently its stuck in compiling for a long time and never finish.

Here is the console :

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p353.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on   binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/gopher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353, this may take a   while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p353, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p353 to /Users/gopher/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p353
ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #extracted to /Users/gopher/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p353
ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #configuring.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #post-configuration
ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #compiling...............
```

It has been running like that for about an hour.
For note, here are my system configuration :
    Mac OS Mountain lion 10.8.5
    RVM v1.24.7
    Command Line Tool v5.0.1

Any ideas?

Many Thanks

Comment: How long is "a long time"? :-) I noticed Ruby 2.0.0 takes quite some time to compile.

Comment: Also, have you (just for good measure) updated your rvm installation? `rvm get stable`

Comment: That's not a problem, as long as the Activity Monitor shows that some work is being done from the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the cause.

It was because older xcode was installed. So, I just removed xcode, and install newest command line tools instead, and it worked.

Thanks!